# Clarification on WPF Window.Show() and Window.Close() and how they work with Multiple Windows

Tags: c#, wpf, navigation, window

The issue I am having and looks like many people have had in the past when 
dealing with WPF is I want to either hide or close the MainWindow of the 
application when a new Window is open. The reason I want to do this is because making tabs for it doesn't look neat to me, especially with how I designed my UI. I have tried using newWindow.Show() and oldWindow.Close(), however when the program runs, the oldWindow is still being shown when it should have been closed. I have also tried making it so the oldWindow is hidden when the newWindow has been called. They both produce the exact same results. As I understand it, You cannot actually close the MainWindow because it is needed for the program to continue to run. So, I know I want to go the route of hiding the MainWindow, but as you can see with my question, it isn't working as intended.
Can anyone possibly explain what I am doing wrong or give pointers for an

alternative method I could go with?

```
namespace WorkinProgress
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// Interaction logic for EnglishLanguageSelection.xaml
            /// </summary>
            public partial class EnglishLanguageSelection : Page
            {
                public EnglishLanguageSelection()
                {
                    InitializeComponent();
                    loadList();
                }

                private void loadList()
                {
                    listBox.Items.Add("math");
                    listBox.Items.Add("science");
                    listBox.Items.Add("history");
                    listBox.Items.Add("english");
                }

                private void listBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, 

SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
                {
                    if (listBox.SelectedIndex == 1)
                    {
            MainWindow main = new MainWindow();
                        ScienceWindow sci = new ScienceWindow();
                        NavigationService.Navigate(sci);
                        main.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I have also tried changing the event handler to:

```
    private void listBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, 

SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (listBox.SelectedIndex == 1)
        {
            MainWindow main = new MainWindow();
            ScienceWindow sci = new ScienceWindow();
            sci.Show();
            main.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> You cannot actually close the MainWindow because it is needed for the
>   program to continue to run

This assertion is wrong, although it is the default behavior, you can set the [`ShutdownMode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.shutdownmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of the `Application` class to either `OnLastWindowClose` or `OnExplicitShutdown`. Then closing the main window won't end your application.

Also, you might want to use the [`Hide`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.hide%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method instead of `Close` since it seems that you want to restore the main window later.

---

About the code you posted, I don't quite understand what you're doing. You're creating a new MainWindow and closing it just after, instead of attempting to close the *already existing* MainWindow.

You seems to be using pages - Are you sure you really want to create *new* windows, and not simply navigate between different pages on the *same* window?

Anyway, here is a possible implementation of your method that should work:

```
private void listBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (listBox.SelectedIndex == 1)
    {
        ScienceWindow sci = new ScienceWindow();
        sci.Show();
        // Note: Better store the main window in a globally accessible place
        // since you want to retrieve it once it is hidden to show it again
        var main = Window.GetWindow(this);
        main.Hide();
    }
}
```

And in App.xaml.cs:

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnStartup(e);
    ShutdownMode = ShutdownMode.OnLastWindowClose;
}
```

Comment: The reason I wanted another Window instead of adding pages, is pretty much due to the structure of the program i'm working on. 
Once you reach a certain point, I wanted to open another window to kind of clear up space without needing to use a menubar. After tons of research and testing, i've found the solution. Instead of using Hide or Show methods on the main menu, I called Application.Current.MainWindow.Close(); and it works as intended.

Although, your suggestion also works.

Comment: Do you understand what does `MainWindow main = new MainWindow();` in the code you posted? Basically you were creating a new main window instead of fetching the existing one - that's what you solved by accessing to the window via `Application.Current.MainWindow`. But that doesn't change the fact that you probably want to use Hide instead of Close and modify the ShutdownMode of your application.

Comment: I understand that it is a method that calls a new MainWindow instead of fetching the existing one. However, accessing the existing one wasn't exactly easy to do.

Comment: I ran a test and the method you described in your answer actually is faster than what I came up with. So, i'm changing my code to reflect this idea over mine.